# How to open md-sidenav on ui-router state load? (Not lock open)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-material

I have a md-sidenav which should be open in some ui-router states but shouldn't in others. I want it to not only *be* open or not but also animate opening/closing between states. Ideally I'd like to have a function which opens sidenav when state/view is loaded.

I tried to do it like this:

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="secondarySidenav" md-disable-backdrop ng-init="handleSecondary()">
```

with function checking $state and opening or closing accordingly, but this didn't work at all and is invalid ng-init usage I think.

Then I did it like:

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="secondarySidenav" md-disable-backdrop md-is-open="handleSecondary()">
```

with function checking $state and returning boolean. It works but sidenav is locked open or closed, doesn't actually open/close between states.

I also tried some functions inside controller but couldn't figure out how to run them in the right moment. Is there some event after loading $state I could hook my function to?

How to make the sidenav animate as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because you are binding `md-is-open` to the return value of the function. This is the model that `md-is-open` is now bound to.

The model returned from that function will never change (in the simple case). Instead you should bind to a variable on the scope.

Something like this.

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="secondarySidenav" md-disable-backdrop md-is-open="secondaryOpen">
```

With your function manipulating the variable

```
function exampleController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.secondaryOpen = false;


    // function for manipulating the sidenav, doesn't have
    // to be attached to $scope if it is not going to be called
    // outside of the enclosing controller func
    $scope.toggleSecondarySideNav = function() {
        $scope.secondaryOpen = !$scope.secondaryOpen;

        // in your function you would manipulate the
        // $scope.secondaryOpen based on the $state;
    }

    // every 5 seconds toggle the sidenav, again in
    // your instance you would just call the function
    $timeout($scope.toggleSecondarySideNav, 5000);
}
exampleController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
angular
  .module('example-module')
  .controller('ExampleController', exampleController);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me when should I call this function which changes variable. When I call it inside controller the variable is set well before the element is even loaded and it is loaded open or not open - doesn't animate.